# How to replace * in A*B with the multiplication symbol in a kable/kableextra html table

Tags: html, r, knitr, kable, kableextra

I am trying to replace an asterisk in the string in a table cell with the multiplication symbol. I can get this to work with kable, but it will not work if I try to use kable_styling. In the picture I have provided, I had to manually edit the html file to make the table on the right.

[What I am trying to do...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNS4c.png)

I use RStudio 1.1.463 with R 3.6.0 and kableExtra 1.1.0 on a Windows 10 machine.

I have tried `gsub("\\*", " &times; ", ...)`  and `gsub("\\*", " \\&times; ", ...)`

with `kable(...)` and `kable(..., escape = F)`

with or without `kable_styling`. (see code)

`---
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: kable
    self_contained: no
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: no
  word_document: default
---`

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

Predictor <- c("A", "B", "A*B")
Statistic <- c(0.8365, 0.8843, -0.9303)
WTest <- data.frame(Predictor = Predictor, Statistic = Statistic)
WTest$Predictor <- gsub("\\*", " &times; ", WTest$Predictor)

kable(WTest) %>% 
kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = FALSE, position = "left")
```

I expected the resulting html code to contain:

`A &times; B`

but the actual output is:

`A &amp;times; B`

I do get the correct result if I use `kable(WTest, escape = F)` and remove the `kable_styling`. But then I lose the bootstrap formatting...

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but why do you need to remove the `kable_styling` when you use `escape = F`? This works for me with `kable(WTest, escape = F) %>% 
kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = FALSE, position = "left")`

Comment: Still doesn't work for me.
I get...
<td style="text-align:left;">
A Ã B
</td>
in the html file.

Comment: I got to thinking... If it works for joshpk, maybe it is a versions problem. It turns out that I can get it to work in R 3.5.3 and with kableExtra 0.9.0. But sadly I need the latest version of kableExtra for another feature to work.